# Fix invalid syntax when defining a variable with numpy library - python

Tags: python, interpolation

I was given this part of the code, and although everything looks okay to me, there's a syntax error. This was the beginning of the code in this Jupyter Notebook.

I've tried changing the variables inside  y_grid=np.zeros(HERE) to be other already defined variables, but that doesn't seem to work, and frankly didn't make sense to do, but I tried it anyways.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def lagrangeinterp(x_data,y_data,x_grid): 
    n=np.size(x_data)
    n_grid=np.size(x_grid)
    L=np.ones([n,n_grid]
    y_grid=np.zeros(n_grid)
```

Here is my error message:
y_grid=np.zeros(x_grid)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Add a `)` after `L=np.ones([n,n_grid]`.